# How to structure a Conversation between two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Store` object that has an email_address attribute. Using the logic from and [How To Build A Form](https://gorails.com/series/how-to-build-a-forum) and [Handling Inbound Email Parsing with Rails](https://gorails.com/episodes/inbound-email-with-rails), I'm trying to figure out how to structure a `Conversation` where a visitor can email the `Store`, and the `Store` can reply through email - their replies would post a `Message` to the `Conversation`.

When a visitor inquires to the store (via form), I create a `Reservation` record with their name and email, and start a `Conversation` like this:

```
@conversation = Conversation.create(sender_id: self.id, recipient_id: self.store_id)
```

I wanted to model the notifications similar to this, where everyone but the sender receives an email, but I'm stumped on how to map the User, since it's two different objects (Reservation and Store):

```
def send_notifications!
    (forum_thread.users.uniq - [user]).each do |user|
      UserMailer.new_post(user, self).deliver_now
    end
  end
```

The Conversation model looks like this, may be wrong, any guidance on what I could use to make the messages unique and structure the notifications?

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: "Reservation"
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: "Store"
  belongs_to :reservation

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: I think the problem is that both are different objects. So it should be `belongs_to :store`, and `belongs_to :user`, then set the direction of travel in a separate attribute `enum direction: [:from, :to]`. Use that direction enum to determine who to send the message. If it's :from send to Store, if it's :to send to User.

Comment: Obviously you should add the column direction to your migration: `rails g migration AddDirectionToConversation direction:string`

Comment: That's a smart approach @bo-oz, let me give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most flexible way would be to set this up as a many-to-many association:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  has_many :conversations, through: :messages
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, through: :messages
end
```

Here `Message` actually works as the join table that ties it together. `Conversion` is the recipient. When sending an initial message to a user you would POST to `/users/:user_id/messages`:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@user, @message || Message.new]) do |f| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

---

```
module Users
  class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    # POST /users/:user_id/messages
    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @conversation = Conversation.joins(:users)
                                  .where(users: { id: [current_user, @user]})
                                  .first_or_create
      @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params.merge(user: current_user))
      if @message.save 
         redirect_to @coversation
      else 
         render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then you would handle the views and controllers (such as a chat window) for conversations in a separate controller:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@conversation, @message || @conversation.messages.new]) do |f| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

---

```
module Conversations
  class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    # POST /conversations/:conversation_id/messages
    def create
      @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
      @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params.merge(user: current_user))
      if @message.save 
         redirect_to @coversation
      else 
         render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```